# Send discontiguous memory to a buffer in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

Suppose I have an array A[200][200].

If I want to send A[0:100][0:200] to GPU buffer,
I just call

```
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, 100 * 200 * sizeof(float), A, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

But if I want to send A[0:200][0:100] to GPU buffer, I cannot call the above function because A[0:200][0:100] is discontiguous.

Is there any wise way to send the above data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [clEnqueueWriteBufferRect](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueWriteBufferRect.html).

```
cl_int clEnqueueWriteBufferRect(    
    cl_command_queue command_queue,
    cl_mem buffer,
    cl_bool blocking_write,
    const size_t buffer_origin[3],
    const size_t host_origin[3],
    const size_t region[3],
    size_t buffer_row_pitch,
    size_t buffer_slice_pitch,
    size_t host_row_pitch,
    size_t host_slice_pitch,
    void *ptr,
    cl_uint num_events_in_wait_list,
    const cl_event *event_wait_list,
    cl_event *event
)
```

In your case, the most relevant parameters are the `host_origin`, `region` and `host_row_pitch`.

**host_row_pitch**: the byte size of each row in memory.
The array `float A[200][200]` describes a row major 2D array with a row pitch of `200 * sizeof(float)`.

**host_origin**: where the host data you wish to send to the device starts. assuming ND array. your origin is simply `size_t[3] {0,0,0}`

**host_region**: the ND region you wish to copy from the array.
your region is size_t[3] {100,200,1}.

I would advise you to read the documentation very carefully. It is easy to make small mistakes.

Also note, that it might be more efficient to first arrange the host data to a continuous array prior to sending it. `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` will probably initiate a DMA transfer which will be more efficient for large continuous blocks of memory.